# Field Service Lightning Managed Packages

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice

I am trying to implement FSL in my developer edition and I could not find the URL to install Managed packages for both Base and Lightning Package. Can someone help me on that?

Comment: For anyone (like me) wondering what this is see [Set Up the Field Service Lightning Managed Package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fs_set_up_packages.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to ask Salesforce.I had the same issue with enabling field service in my client org.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a link through which you can install the Field Service Lightning Managed Package.

There are also links to the documentation and a guide for migration to the new standard object model of FSL.

https://fsl.secure.force.com/install/